# Background color not rendering in Safari

Tags: css, safari, less

Is there any reason why my background color is not appearing but all other background attributes are in Safari... I am using LESS.

Example:

1) This DOES NOT render the background a color in Safari:

```
background: @lightGray url(/assets/project_title_icon.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
```

2) This DOES render the background a color in Safari:

```
background: url(/assets/project_title_icon.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
background-color: @lightGray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples should result in the same thing. [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/LPGzZ/2/), but I don't have safari :/

What does this Fiddle look like in Safari?

```
div {
    background: green url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: they look exactly the same for me in Safari 6.0.3

Comment: So weird Robert, but your code didn't render a background color for me in Safari Version 6.0.5. I have no idea!